# Keras for R: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_numpy'

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras from R, trying to implement a custom loss function following https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/59 (essentially convert tensors to R objects, then compute the loss in R, and convert back to a tensor).

However, I get the following error message which I don't understand. From other questions, I got the impression that this might have to do something with eager execution not being enabled, but this should be the case for my versions of Keras and tensorflow (see below)?

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  RuntimeError: Evaluation error: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_numpy'.
```

Here is the output of `devtools::session_info` for Keras and Tensorflow (and R) versions:

```
─ Session info ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
 os       Ubuntu 20.04 LTS            
 system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
 ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
 tz       Europe/Berlin               
 date     2020-05-25                  

─ Packages ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package     * version      date       lib source                        
 assertthat    0.2.1        2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 backports     1.1.7        2020-05-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 base64enc     0.1-3        2015-07-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 callr         3.4.3        2020-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 cli           2.0.2        2020-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 crayon        1.3.4        2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 desc          1.2.0        2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 devtools      2.3.0        2020-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 digest        0.6.25       2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 ellipsis      0.3.1        2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 fansi         0.4.1        2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 fs            1.4.1        2020-04-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 generics      0.0.2        2018-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)                
 glue          1.4.1        2020-05-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 jsonlite      1.6.1        2020-02-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 keras       * 2.3.0.0.9000 2020-05-22 [1] Github (rstudio/keras@561e748)
 lattice       0.20-41      2020-04-02 [4] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 magrittr      1.5          2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                
 Matrix        1.2-18       2019-11-27 [4] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                
 memoise       1.1.0        2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 pkgbuild      1.0.8        2020-05-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 pkgload       1.0.2        2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 prettyunits   1.1.1        2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 processx      3.4.2        2020-02-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 ps            1.3.3        2020-05-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 R6            2.4.1        2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 rappdirs      0.3.1        2016-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 Rcpp          1.0.4.6      2020-04-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 remotes       2.1.1        2020-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 reticulate  * 1.15         2020-04-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 rlang         0.4.6        2020-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 rprojroot     1.3-2        2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 rstudioapi    0.11         2020-02-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 sessioninfo   1.1.1        2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 tensorflow  * 2.2.0        2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 testthat      2.3.2        2020-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 tfruns        1.4          2018-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 usethis       1.6.1        2020-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 whisker       0.4          2019-08-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 withr         2.2.0        2020-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)                
 zeallot       0.1.0        2018-01-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
```